# bounded service using messenger downloading images

Tags: android

I am not able to download image using messenger in boundservice eventhough in android manifest showing service in separate process

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.vuum.mocca"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
        <activity
            android:name="edu.vuum.mocca.DownloadActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <service android:name="edu.vuum.mocca.DownloadService" android:process=":my_process"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Dowloadservice handler calling dowloadmessageandRespond it gives `android.os.networkonmainthreadexception`

But services handler runs in separate process so above execution shouldn't come?

If i do dowloadmessageandRespond method in separate thread then program  runs fine  which  commented in dowloadmessageandRespond method.

```
package edu.vuum.mocca;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * @class DownloadService
 *
 * @brief DownloadService receives an Intent containing a URL (which
 *        is a type of URI) and a Messenger. It downloads the file at
 *        the URL, stores it on the file system, then returns the path
 *        name to the caller using the supplied Messenger.
 * 
 *        The DownloadService class implements the CommandProcessor
 *        pattern and The Messenger is used as part of the Active
 *        Object pattern.
 */
public class DownloadService extends Service 
{
    /**
     * Used for debugging.
     */
    private final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private final static int LOG_OP = 1;
    /**
     * Looper associated with the HandlerThread.
     */
  //  private volatile Looper mServiceLooper;

    /**
     * Implementation a Messenger that encapsulates the RequestHandler
     * used to handle request Messages sent from the
     * UniqueIDGeneratorActivity.
     */
    private final static String MESSAGE_URL = "course.examples.Services.Logging.MESSAGE";
     final Messenger mMessengerImpl =
            new Messenger(new ServiceHandler());

    /**
     * Factory method to make the desired Intent.
     */
    public static Intent makeIntent(Context context

                                   ) {
        // Create the Intent that's associated to the DownloadService
        // class.
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                                   DownloadService.class);


        return intent;
    }

    /**
     * @class ServiceHandler
     *
     * @brief An inner class that inherits from Handler and uses its
     *        handleMessage() hook method to process Messages sent to
     *        it from onStartCommnand() that indicate which images to
     *        download.
     */
    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {


        /**
         * A factory method that creates a Message to return to the
         * DownloadActivity with the pathname of the downloaded image.
         */
        private Message makeReplyMessage(String pathname){
            Message message = Message.obtain();
            // Return the result to indicate whether the download
            // succeeded or failed.
            message.arg1 = pathname == null 
                ? Activity.RESULT_CANCELED 
                : Activity.RESULT_OK;

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            // Pathname for the downloaded image.
            bundle.putString("PATHNAME", 
                             pathname);
            message.setData(bundle);
            return message;
        }

        /**
         * A factory method that creates a Message that contains
         * information on the image to download and how to stop the
         * Service.
         */
/*        private Message makeDownloadMessage(Intent intent,
                                            int startId){
            Message message = Message.obtain();
            // Include Intent & startId in Message to indicate which URI
            // to retrieve and which request is being stopped when
            // download completes.
            message.obj = intent;
            message.arg1 = startId;
            return message;
        }*/

        /**
         * Retrieves the designated image and reply to the
         * DownloadActivity via the Messenger .
         */
        private void downloadImageAndReply(Message message) {
            final Messenger messenger = message.replyTo;
            final String url=message.getData().getString(MESSAGE_URL);
             // Download the requested image.
            //final String pathname;
//          new Thread( new Runnable() {
//              public void run(){
                String pathname = downloadImage(DownloadService.this,url);
                Log.d(TAG, "pathname----- after downloadImage()"+pathname);

                sendPath(messenger, pathname);
//              }
//          }).start();
        }

        /**
         * Send the pathname back to the DownloadActivity via the
         * messenger.
         */
        private void sendPath(Messenger messenger, 
                              String pathname) {
            // Call factory method to create Message.
            Message message = makeReplyMessage(pathname);

            try {
                if (messenger == null)
                    Log.d(TAG, "replyMessenger is null");
                else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "sending key" + pathname);
                // Send pathname to back to the DownloadActivity.
                    messenger.send(message);
                }
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                      "Exception while sending.",
                      e);
            }
        }

    /**
     * Create a file to store the result of a download.
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param url
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private File getTemporaryFile(final Context context,
                                      final String url) throws IOException {
            return context.getFileStreamPath(Base64.encodeToString(url.getBytes(),
                                                                   Base64.NO_WRAP)
                                             + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    /**
     * Copy the contents of an InputStream into an OutputStream.
     * 
     * @param in
     * @param out
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private int copy(final InputStream in,
                         final OutputStream out) throws IOException {
            final int BUFFER_LENGTH = 1024;
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];
            int totalRead = 0;
            int read = 0;

            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                totalRead += read;          
            }

            return totalRead;
    }

    /**
     * Download the requested image and return the local file path.
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param url
     * @return
     */
    public String downloadImage(final Context context,
                                    final String url) {
            try {
                final File file = getTemporaryFile(context, url);
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), "    downloading to " + file);

                final InputStream in = (InputStream)
                    new URL(url).getContent();
                final OutputStream out =
                    new FileOutputStream(file);

                copy(in, out);
                in.close();
                out.close();
                return file.getAbsolutePath();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                      "Exception while downloading. Returning null.");
                Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                      e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
    }

        /**
         * Hook method that retrieves an image from a remote server.
         */
        public void handleMessage( Message message) {
            // Download the designated image and reply to the
            // DownloadActivity via the Messenger sent with the
            // Intent.


            switch (message.what) {

            case LOG_OP:

                Log.i(TAG, message.getData().getString(MESSAGE_URL));

                            downloadImageAndReply(message);



                break;

            default:

                super.handleMessage(message);

            }



        }
    }

    /**
     * Hook method called when DownloadService is first launched by
     * the Android ActivityManager.
     */
 /*   public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Create and start a background HandlerThread since by
        // default a Service runs in the UI Thread, which we don't
        // want to block.
        HandlerThread thread =
            new HandlerThread("DownloadService");
        thread.start();

        // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler.
        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler =
            new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    }*/

    /**
     * Hook method called each time a Started Service is sent an
     * Intent via startService().
     */
/*    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, 
                              int flags,
                              int startId) {
        // Create a Message that will be sent to ServiceHandler to
        // retrieve animagebased on the URI in the Intent.
        Message message =
            mServiceHandler.makeDownloadMessage(intent,
                                                startId);

        // Send the Message to ServiceHandler to retrieve an image
        // based on contents of the Intent.
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(message);

        // Don't restart the DownloadService automatically if its
        // process is killed while it's running.
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }*/



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mMessengerImpl.getBinder();
    }
}
```

downloadactivity downloadimage method  Called when a user clicks the Download Image button to download image using the DownloadService

```
package edu.vuum.mocca;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * @class DownloadActivity
 * 
 * @brief A class that allows a user to download a bitmap image using
 *        a DownloadService.
 */
public class DownloadActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Used for debugging.
     */
    private final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private final static int LOG_OP = 1;
    private final static String MESSAGE_URL = "course.examples.Services.Logging.MESSAGE";
    private boolean mIsBound;
    /**
     * User's selection of URL to download
     */
    private EditText mUrlEditText;

    /**
     * Image that's been downloaded
     */
    private ImageView mImageView;

    /**
     * Default URL.
     */
    private String mDefaultUrl = 
        "http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/ka.png";

    /**
     * Display progress of download
     */
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


    /**
     * Reference to the Messenger that's implemented in the
     * UniqueIDGeneratorService.
     */
    private Messenger mMessengerRef = null;

    /** 
     * This ServiceConnection is used to receive a Messenger proxy
     * after binding to the UniqueIDGeneratorService using bindService().
     */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            /**
             * Called after the UniqueIDGeneratorService is connected to
             * convey the result returned from onBind().
             */
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                           IBinder messenger) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "ComponentName:" + className);

                // Create a newq Messenger that encapsulates the
                // returned IBinder object and store it for later use
                // in mMessengerRef.
                mMessengerRef = new Messenger(messenger);
                mIsBound = true;
            }

            /**
             * Called if the Service crashes and is no longer
             * available.  The ServiceConnection will remain bound,
             * but the service will not respond to any requests.
             */
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
                mMessengerRef = null;


                mIsBound = false;
            }
    };


    /**
     * Method that initializes the Activity when it is first created.
     * 
     * @param savedInstanceState
     *            Activity's previously frozen state, if there was one.
     */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         * Sets the content view specified in the main.xml file.
         */
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /**
         * Caches references to the EditText and ImageView objects in
         * data members to optimize subsequent access.
         */
        mUrlEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mUrlEditText);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
    }

    /**
     * Show a toast, notifying a user of an error when retrieving a
     * bitmap.
     */
    void showErrorToast(String errorString) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                       errorString,
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * Display a downloaded bitmap image if it's non-null; otherwise,
     * it reports an error via a Toast.
     * 
     * @param image
     *            The bitmap image
     */
    void displayImage(Bitmap image)
    {   
        if (mImageView == null)
            showErrorToast("Problem with Application,"
                           + " please contact the Developer.");
        else if (image != null)
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        else
            showErrorToast("image is corrupted,"
                           + " please check the requested URL.");
    }

    /**
     * Called when a user clicks a button to reset an image to
     * default.
     * 
     * @param view
     *            The "Reset Image" button
     */
    public void resetImage(View view) {
        mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_image);
    }

    /**
     * Called when a user clicks the Download Image button to download
     * an image using the DownloadService
     * 
     * @param view
     *            The "Download Image" button
     */
    public void downloadImage(View view) {
        // Obtain the requested URL from the user input.
        if (mIsBound) {
        String url = getUrlString();

        Log.e(DownloadActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
              "Downloading " + url);

        hideKeyboard();

        // Inform the user that the download is starting.
        showDialog("downloading via startService()");
     // Create a request Message that indicates the Service should
        // send the reply back to ReplyHandler encapsulated by the
        // Messenger.
        Message msg = Message.obtain(null, LOG_OP);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MESSAGE_URL, url);
        msg.setData(bundle);

       // Message request = Message.obtain();
        msg.replyTo = new Messenger(new DownloadHandler(this));

        try {
            if (mMessengerRef != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "sending message to service with url");
                // Send the request Message to the
                // UniqueIDGeneratorService.
                mMessengerRef.send(msg);
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Create an Intent to download an image in the background via
        // a Service.  The downloaded image is later diplayed in the
        // UI Thread via the downloadHandler() method defined below.
     //  DownloadService.makeIntent(this, Uri.parse( getUrlString()));

        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "service is not bounded restat again");
        }
    }
    /**
     * Hook method called by Android when this Activity becomes
     * visible.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart()");

        Log.d(TAG, "calling bindService()");
        if (mMessengerRef == null)
            // Bind to the UniqueIDGeneratorService associated with this
            // Intent.
            bindService(DownloadService.makeIntent(this),
                        this.mConnection,
                        Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
         super.onStop();
         if (mIsBound)
            unbindService(mConnection);
    }

    /**
     * @class DownloadHandler
     *
     * @brief An inner class that inherits from Handler and uses its
     *        handleMessage() hook method to process Messages sent to
     *        it from the DownloadService.
     */
    private static class DownloadHandler extends Handler {
        /**
         * Allows Activity to be garbage collected properly.
         */
        private WeakReference<DownloadActivity> mActivity;

        /**
         * Class constructor constructs mActivity as weak reference
         * to the activity
         * 
         * @param activity
         *            The corresponding activity
         */
        public DownloadHandler(DownloadActivity activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<DownloadActivity>(activity);
        }

        /**
        /**
         * This hook method is dispatched in response to receiving
         * the pathname back from the DownloadService.
         */
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            DownloadActivity activity = mActivity.get();
            // Bail out of the DownloadActivity is gone.
            if (activity == null)
                return;

            // Extract the data from Message, which is in the form
            // of a Bundle that can be passed across processes.
            Bundle data = msg.getData();

            // Extract the pathname from the Bundle.
            String pathname = data.getString("PATHNAME");

            // See if things worked or not.
            if (msg.arg1 != RESULT_OK || pathname == null)
                activity.showDialog("failed download");

            // Stop displaying the progress dialog.
            activity.dismissDialog();

            // Display the image in the UI Thread.
            activity.displayImage(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathname));
        }
    };



    /**
     * Display the Dialog to the User.
     * 
     * @param message 
     *          The String to display what download method was used.
     */
    public void showDialog(String message) {
        mProgressDialog =
            ProgressDialog.show(this,
                                "Download",
                                message,
                                true);
    }

    /**
     * Dismiss the Dialog
     */
    public void dismissDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null)
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    /**
     * Hide the keyboard after a user has finished typing the url.
     */
    private void hideKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager mgr =
            (InputMethodManager) getSystemService
            (Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mUrlEditText.getWindowToken(),
                                    0);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.download, menu);
        return true;
    }




    /**
     * Read the URL EditText and return the String it contains.
     * 
     * @return String value in mUrlEditText
     */
    String getUrlString() {
        String s = mUrlEditText.getText().toString();
        if (s.equals(""))
            s = mDefaultUrl;
        return s;
    }

}
```

Bound service with messenger ,if it is running in separate process doesn't need separate thread to do long running task.

I need to know why this service of downloadimage not working even though its running in separate process.

Thanks for helping .

Comment: Could you please narrow down the question to your problem if possible, it seems too long.

Comment: I would like to use boundservice meseenger for long running proceess downloading image.My question why my service onhandlemessage doesnt dowload image eventhough service running in separate proceess ts giving error android.os.networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 0):

As there is a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` the solution is to put the network code in an `AsyncTask` or `thread`.

Comment: what do you mean as a network code please explain.
Or there is only option to do long running task as backgroundthread

Comment: Network code is all code that is executed when your app connects with a server on internet or your LAN and is using streams to send or receive data.